# Vbscript in Firefox

Tags: asp.net

Does firefox have VBScript & Activex support?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Firefox doesn't support either one. (Neither does Chrome.)

Answer (score 1):

VBScript isn’t available. ActiveX can be added through a plugin ( http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/ ) but I’d suggest re-evaluating what you’re trying to do as obviously this is limited to Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

No, I beleive that VBScript (thank god) is IE only. Maybe Javascript could be a replacement?

What is it you are trying to do?